# Is it possible to return multiple items from View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public List<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
    public List<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
    public List<Drink> DrinksOrdered { get; set; }
    public List<Meal> MealsOrdered { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel OrderViewModel where Drinks and Meals are from database, and DrinksOrdered and MealsOrdered are to be filled in View

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new OrderViewModel
            {
                Meals = _context.Meals.ToList(),
                Drinks = _context.Drinks.ToList()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Code from my OrderController.

```
@model App.ViewModel.OrderViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int i = 0;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<h2>Order</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Finish", "Order"))
{
    <div id="order" class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.MealsOrdered[i].Name)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Meals[i].Id, new SelectList(Model.Meals, "Id", "Name"), "Select Meal...", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="AddMeal">Add a Meal </button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let i = 0;
        $('#AddMeal').click(() => {
            let label = $('<label>Name:</label>');
            let input = $(`@Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Meals[i].Id, new SelectList(Model.Meals, "Id", "Name"), "Select Meal...", new { @class = "form-control" })`);

            $('#order').append(label);
            $('#order').append(input);
        })
    });
</script>
```

There is a button, and when you click it, a new dropdown menu appears. It only offers Meals for now, but I wonder is it possible to select a few Meals, put them in the List from @model as Model.MealsOrdered[i].Name and later forward that with form.

Comment: Yes, that is possible! Make sure the structure of data you posting to controller should match the parameter in action method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, just need to be sure that you post elements properly named to your controller be able to detect and bind the values..

In your case the names of items in MealsOrdered
Must to be something like "MealsOrdered[n].Id".

You can create hidden inputs to post your oredered lists.

Just remember that the first element is binded to index 0